# How can div keep its minimum height inside grid layout?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have grid-layout with grid template columns set to (auto auto auto).
Then, in each grid I have a div, inside div some text. All divs have same height, but I want each div's height to be as minimum as it can be. Here's example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #42cbf5;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.articles {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}

.article {
  display: inline;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 50px;
  display: block;
  min-height: 5%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="articles">

        <div class="article">
          <p>TEST</p>
        </div>

        <div class="article">
          <p>TEST</p>
        </div>

        <div class="article">
          <p>TEST</p>
          <p>TEST</p>
          <p>TEST</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Each white div has equal height, it depends on the highest div in each row. How can I change it? I've tried different display: block/inline/inline-block, nothing worked.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`margin: auto;` on your article class will keep the div size minimal. You'll have to compensate with some padding maybe, depending on what you're going for exactly

```
.article {
          display: inline;
          background-color: white;
          margin: auto;
          display: block;
          min-height: 5%;
          position: relative;
          padding: 5px;
        }
```

Comment: It was that, easy, thanks! I will accept this as an answer as soon as I can. Also, margin: 50px 50px auto 50px; works just as I wanted.